# Why does the order of registering my ViewEngines seem immaterial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have written a test ViewEngine which responds to requests with a view name of "About", and added the following to the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine());
```

The `FindView` method of `MyViewEngine` is as follows:

```
if (viewName == "About")
    return new ViewEngineResult(new MyView(), this);
return new ViewEngineResult(new List<string>{"Some arbitrary search location"});
```

As the Home controller responds to the action About, I would have expected the `RazorViewEngine` to handle a request for `~/Home/About` (as it was added to the `Engines` collection first) but it's not... `MyViewEngine` is handling calls to that URL instead.

Calls which result in views not named "About" are handled correctly by Razor.

Even if I reverse the order of the two `Add` statements above, I get the exact same behavior.  If I comment out the code which registers my view engine, Razor does pick up `~/Home/About` as I would expect.

Any ideas why `MyViewEngine` is creating views ahead of Razor when it shouldn't be?

Comment: Do you actually have a ~/views/home/about.cshtml file in your application?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I've just added my ViewEngine to a new MVC3 project created from the template for testing purposes.

Comment: Do you use a custom `DependencyResolver`? If yes did you register your `ViewEngine` in it?

Comment: No, this is just the default MVC3 project template, with a new view engine added, and the change to Global.asax.cs to register it... nothing else other than that. It's got me baffled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC asks the registered `ViewEngines` in their registration order as expected. However there is one catch. It's in the `ViewEngineCollection` [`FindView`](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70574#266524) method:

```
public virtual ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName)
```

This method iterates through the available `ViewEngines` asking for a view but it does it twice. Once with calling the `FindView` method with `useCache=true` and if none of the `ViewEngines` provided a result it iterates over them another time with `useCache=false`.
So in your case when it asks the `RazorViewEngine` with `useCache=true` it does not return a view because there is no chached one. But your view engine will always provide `View`. So you need to handle the `useCache=true` case in your implementation:

```
public ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
{
    if (useCache)
        return new ViewEngineResult(new List<string> { "Not in cache" });

    if (viewName == "About")
        return new ViewEngineResult(new MyView(), this);
    return new ViewEngineResult(new List<string> { "Some arbitrary search location" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nemesv. Wrox's Professional ASP.NET MVC 3 provides just enough info about writing ViewEngines to be dangerous, and doesn't mention the useCache parameter at all. This worked perfectly!